# Checking dialog prompt with robotium - Need if statement if not

Tags: java, testing, automation, robotium

I am attempting to write a few testcases for automation using robotium. I believe my question is easy but I haven't found a solution yet.

I have a dialog prompt ("OK") that is triggered only about 50% of the time. I want this test case to check if the dialog box was prompt, if it is I need to click "OK". If it was not prompt continue logging in.

```
        // Entering "test" into the password field
        solo.enterText((EditText) solo
                .findViewById("com.mobile.R.id.passwordEditText"),
                "test");
        // Pressing ENTER from the keyboard
        solo.sendKey(ExtSolo.ENTER);
        
        //waiting 5.1 Seconds
        solo.sleep(5100);
        
        // This is where I'm stuck
        /*
         * What I want: 
         * I want to look for the OK button, but if its not found to continue without it.
                     * If dialog button was not found, continue to login.
         */
        assertTrue("Wait for button (text: OK) failed.",
                solo.waitForButton("OK", 20000));
        solo.clickOnButton("OK");
        //login
                    solo.clickOnButton("login");
```

Thank you!

EDIT
Maybe I can surpress the token from prompting on login, but I would rather be able to click ok if it is there, or login still if it is not without failing the test case.

solo.getView(String id) I can see if it exist with this, but it will fail if it is not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are, it should help:

```
if (solo.waitForButton("OK", 20000)) {
    solo.clickOnButton("OK");
} 
solo.clickOnButton("login");
```

Comment: if you have multiple languages, it's better to use:
`solo.clickOnButton(getActivity().getString(android.R.string.ok));`